# web2py SQLFORM update form issue

Tags: web2py

I'm trying to create a simple update profile update form for my application. I've created a custom table named "person" to hold the various users, and have successfully created a registration page/form and login page/form. However, I'm having difficulty creating the profile update form.

According to the web2py book I should be able to do something like:

```
def profile():
    record = db.person(1)
    form = SQLFORM(db.person, record)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = "HEY"
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = "HO"
    return dict(selected="progress", username=auth.user.username, form=form)
```

But the page only displays "None"

The weird thing is when I change my code to be:

```
def profile():
return dict(selected="progress", username=auth.user.username, form=db.person[1])
```

The data under the "form" key is the row that I am trying to get from the database.

So when I'm trying to query the database in the first rendition of my code, I get "None" in return. Which according to the web2py book means that the row wasn't found. However, when I immediately return the query, as in the second rendition of my code, I am successful in retrieving the desired row.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the view code:

```
{{extend 'arlayout.html'}}
<div id="progress" class="main_view">
{{=form}}
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the page only displays 'None'"? If `db.person(1)` returns `None`, then the page would simply display a create form, not `None`. Can you show the view code?

Comment: Updated post to show view code

Comment: I tried your exact code and cannot reproduce the problem. I suggest you pack a minimal app that reproduces the problem and post it on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py).

Comment: Is something else going on in the code somewhere? Your controller returns `selected` and `username`, but the view doesn't use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to edit the user's own profile you can simply do:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def profile():
    return dict(form=auth.profile())
```

If you are trying to edit the profile of a different user, you may want to restrict access to a specific group of users:

```
@auth.requires_memebership('profile-editors')
def profile():
    user_id = request.args(0,cast=int,default=auth.user.id)
    return dict(form=SQLFORM(db.auth_user,user_id).process())
```